# HttpClient random exception with Azure Container Instance

Tags: c#, azure-container-instances

HttpClient throw a random exception ( maybe 2-3 times out of 10 attempts ) with Azure Container Instance

> Exception Info:  System.Net.WebException at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(System.IAsyncResult) at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
>   Exception Info: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>   at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClient+\u003cFinishSendAsync\u003ed__58.MoveNext()
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSucem.Net.Http.HttpClient+\u003cFinishSendAsync\u003ed__58.MoveNext()
>   at
>   SystetHelpers.MSIResourcesAccessInfoHelper+\u003cGetResourcesAccessInfo\u003ed__0.MoveNext()\n.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n
>   at System.Runtime.m[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c56193ompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.ThreC.Main(System.String[])

On the code side, I am simply firing

```
await httpClient.GetAsync($"http://xyz.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/api/controller/{id}");
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ResourceAccessInfo>();
```

The behavior is very random it happens only 2-3 time out of 10 attempts 
I have also applied re-try when the first attempt then try the second time but still it fails

Same works fine with VM containers always.

Updated:

Additional Exception Info:
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---\u003e System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: \u0027cloudbridge1.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com\u0027\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.\u003cFinishSendAsync\u003ed__58.MoveNext()\r\n--- End ofstack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at UcClearly.MSIAPIHelpers.MSIResourcesAccessInfoHelper.\u003cGetResourcesAccessInfo\u003ed__0.MoveNext()

Which suggest remote server DNS not resolved,  I tried with public IP of the server also but same random behavior, I am not sure why Azure Container instance behave this random way

Comment: You did call `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();`. That means `"throw exception if the result isn't in the 2xx range`. Where is the rest of the exception? It should contain the actual status code and response body

Comment: but the server is not throwing an exception I am just returning a string from the server, Somewhere HttpClient is not able to reach to the server when gets executed within azure container instance and this happens randomly

Comment: Post the *full exception*. Or change the code and *inspect* the response instead of calling `EnsureSuccessStatusCode()`. If you get a 400 because the call was bad or 404 because there's no such ID you'll never know it

Comment: added exception details to post

Comment: A DNS error can't be fixed with code. Either the DNS name is wrong or the remote server is *not* running all the time. Perhaps a configuration error shuts down the container too soon, or doesn't bring it back up when it should?

Comment: Just, not the DNS, it's also showing random behavior with public IP

Comment: Which is exactly what would happen if the container was down

Comment: Container is up , I am getting all exception details from event log of container itself , it's a windows container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is expected.

> **Windows containers slow network readiness**
>   On initial creation, Windows containers may have no inbound or outbound connectivity for up to 30 seconds (or longer, in rare cases). If your container application needs an Internet connection, add delay and retry logic to allow 30 seconds to establish Internet connectivity. After initial setup, container networking should resume appropriately.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting#windows-containers-slow-network-readiness